# Test if Polars Series values are equal

Tags: python, python-polars

Polars has the `Series.series_equal` method for testing if two series are equal. Part of this test is that the name of each series is equal also. Is there a way to test only if the values are equal?

```py
import polars as pl

a = pl.Series("a", [1,2,3])
b = pl.Series("b", [1,2,3])

a.series_equal(b)
# False
```

Answer (score 3):

See https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/testing.html

e.g. [`polars.testing.assert_series_equal()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.testing.assert_series_equal.html#polars.testing.assert_series_equal)

```
import polars.testing

polars.testing.assert_series_equal(a, b, check_names=False)
```

Comment: Code for "testing" usually is not suitable for runtime, without a good reason. This, for example, will raise an AssertionError if they differ, when one usually just want a `False` value as a result.

Comment: @jsbueno The equal functions in `polars.testing` have extra functionality which may be desired e.g. `check_dtype`, `check_exact`, `atol`, `rtol`. And yes, they raise - so you would use a try/except.

Answer (score 1):

`(a == b).all()` will do. There is some overhead, but it should have minimal impact for the great majority of use cases.

```
In [7]: import polars as pl
   ...: 
   ...: a = pl.Series("a", [1,2,3])
   ...: b = pl.Series("b", [1,2,3])

In [8]: a == b
Out[8]: 
shape: (3,)
Series: 'a' [bool]
[
        true
        true
        true
]

In [9]: (a == b).all()
Out[9]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `==` operator to compare the Series directly.

```
import polars as pl

a = pl.Series("a", [1, 2, 3])
b = pl.Series("b", [1, 2, 3])

values_equal = a == b

print(values_equal)

# output: [true, true, true]
```

Note that this comparison is element-wise, so it checks the equality of each value in the Series.

To check if all the values in the Boolean Series are True, you can use the `all()` method. Here's an example of how to incorporate it into the code:

```
all_equal = values_equal.all()

print(all_equal)
# output: True
```

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to convert both to NumPy arrays, which loses the name information, and then use `numpy.array_equal` to test the values for equality.

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

a = pl.Series("a", [1,2,3])
b = pl.Series("b", [1,2,3])

np.array_equal(a.to_numpy(), b.to_numpy(), equal_nan=True)
# True
```